Performance Issue with Polyline Rendering on React Leaflet Map
I am experiencing a performance issue with the polyline component of the Leaflet map library in React.js. I have a large dataset of traffic congestion data (approximately 5,000 to 10,000 polylines) that needs to be rendered on the map. When I zoom in or out, the polylines are supposed to update accordingly. However, this causes significant lag and delays in rendering the map. The system becomes unresponsive during these operations.
Is there a way to optimize the performance of polyline rendering in React Leaflet when dealing with large datasets? Any advice or best practices would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a brief overview of my current setup:

React.js for the frontend framework
React Leaflet for the map component
Large dataset of traffic congestion data that needs to be visualized with polylines

Thank you in advance for your help!
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I tried several optimization techniques such as using React.memo to memoize the polyline components, implementing debouncing for the zoom events, and reducing the complexity of the polyline data. I expected these changes to improve the rendering performance and make the map interactions smoother.
What actually happened?
Despite these efforts, the performance issue persists. The map still experiences significant lag and becomes unresponsive during zoom operations, especially when dealing with the large dataset of polylines. The expected improvements in rendering performance were not achieved.

Did you look at the performance tools of your browser to see where it is actually spending time when you render or zoom such a dataset? If the time is spent e.g. within leaflet, there's not much reason to even consider React.memo.

It's also possible that Leaflet is simply not the right tool for a large dataset like this, and you'll need a more performant renderer such as https://maplibre.org/ (https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/ for the React wrapper).

That's why I linked the freely usable maplibre, not paid mapbox. Anyway, might be possible with Leaflet, but as I said to begin with: measure and profile first.
